# Linux kernel, I2C SPI buses, and time slices?

Tags: linux, embedded, kernel, driver, atomic

Kind of a weird question, but I'm in a class about linux kernel driver development and the prof couldn't answer this.

Let's suppose I have a finite state machine of some kind attached to an SPI or I2C bus (In real life this is actually an accelerometer, but the implementation isn't important). If I write a misc character driver for it, and insmod it, any user on the system can now access this device.

Let's suppose that I want to read 200 bytes of data from this FSM device. A read is performed by sending the register address of the data location, and performing a continuous read until I have my 200 bytes (program#1).

The confusion comes in when I know my user level program is getting time-sliced. If another (program#2) user level program is also going to ask for 10 bytes from this accelerometer, it will address and continuously read until it has it's 10 bytes.

If program#1 has run and read 50 bytes when it gets time-sliced out, and program#2 is run to completion, then when program#1 returns, the address it was reading from is corrupted, and it's reading data from the wrong address.

Time slices are invisible to the user. As far as I know they're also invisible to the kernel driver code. Is there some mechanism to avoid this? Atomic read and writes would make the most sense, but these I2C/SPI devices are slow by CPU standards. I can't imagine the CPU would sit idly by for the entire time just to ensure an I2C/SPI read/write is atomic?

The answer the prof gave me is that this problem has been solved for memory a long time ago, and linux is "probably doing something fancy under the hood" to make it happen. But that didn't really address the root of the question. I'd love a proper answer. If anyone can recommend better search terms to approach the question I would also appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Sometimes you also have a driver in the kernel for the device. The driver is immune from preemption and/or has some kind of locking mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question right, the whole problem is about locking the device that is used by multiple programs *(threads, etc.)* and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874962/linux-device-driver-file-operations-it-is-possible-to-have-race-conditions) may have an answer to it.

Your professor was partially right. The problem was discovered a long time ago, it's called the [race conditions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch05.html). But, the solution isn't provided by the kernel itself in a *fancy* way. It is the user's responsibility to implement a mechanism that can prevent race conditions on devices or any other resources.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much!