# How Device unbinding from driver works? Does unregister of device waits for fops to complete?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am trying to understand how device unbinding works?
I have a module with which two devices are attached.

- Dev1
- Dev2

Devices dev1 and dev2 are created in probe function.

Each device(dev1/dev2) creates one more char device under it.
Basically the module has probe and remove
Probe creates device which registers one more char device (with char device own file operations)

remove functionality is for the module(dev1/dev2)

Dev1 & Dev 2, registered char device file operations includes ioctl.

Issue:
Unbinding of device dev1 or dev2 does not wait for char device file operations to finish.
So every time unbind of device happens while ioctl is in progress, system gives oops.

Tried to open and release in fops for the device but didnt help.
Include debug Print in char device fops, release,
the debug print is seen after the device is unbinded.(verified with debug print in remove of dev1/dev2)

Current debug print seq:

```
~~~ Device removed ~~~ (from module remove)
~~~ Char device released ~~~ (from char device)
```

Expectation:
Unbinding of device(dev1/dev2) should wait for the char device fops to complete.
Expected debug print seq:

```
~~~ Char device released ~~~ (from char device)
~~~ Device removed ~~~ (from module remove)
```

Comment: "unbind" means, rmmod ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874962/linux-device-driver-file-operations-it-is-possible-to-have-race-conditions

Comment: @Haswell, it's not the same. Unbind is done unconditionally.

Comment: Your problem with understanding lifetime of the object instances and not directly related to the binding or unbinding the devices to  or from the driver. When you have Oops, you missed the refcounting of the driver, device, and/or something else.